# How to prevent a class from being build into the release DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

It is possible to exclude classes from being build into the DLL?

I like to exclude the classes from being present in the **release** version. Debug version can have the classes.

Comment: Use conditional compilation symbols.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [C# preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/index) for that. In your debug version, there should be a symbol `DEBUG` defined, which is not defined in your release version. So your code could look like this:

```
#if DEBUG
public class MyClassForDebugOnly
{
    // ...
}
#endif
```

So this class will not be available (compiled) in a release version. But note that no code that *is* compiled in the release version can reference this class.

---

To define preprocessor symbols (like `DEBUG`) you can open your project properties page (right click on the project and select "Properties..."), go to the "Build" tab and edit the "Conditional compilation symbols" (a comma separated list of symbols).
For the two symbols `DEBUG` and `TRACE` there are two extra checkboxes which (afaik) are checked by default for debug configurations.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it, but this should work:

```
#if (DEBUG)

public class ReleaseOnly
{

}

#endif
```

Comment: just be noted, that everywhere this class is used you should add the #if #endif

Comment: @elibyy Would something like my answer be a better solution?

Comment: @ReeceCottam it still should be the same, just more neat, the simpler way is the pre-processing directives

Comment: I agree, but I think that preprocessor directives can be more restrictive than putting conditions in the Project file because as mentioned, you'd need to put a preprocessor directive on each class you need, but that is just my opinion =]

Answer (score 2):

In your Project file, insert something like this;

```
<CSFile Include="*.cs" Exclude="Excludedfile.cs"/>
```

and to do it conditionally, use something like this;

```
<Compile
    Exclude="Excludedfile.vb"
    Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' " />
```

Check out [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171455.aspx) for more information, I hope this helps, you specified that this should be excluded from the **build**, so I thought this was more like what you wanted as opposed to a preprocessor directive :)

Comment: Just FYI a different MSFT article also mentions this approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/april/mvvm-maximizing-the-visual-designer%E2%80%99s-usage-with-design-time-data#excluding-design-time-data-from-production-builds